# Should or can Visual Studio run inside App-V and what are the repurcussions?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

There is a debate going in our department to virtualize Visual Studio into App-V, Microsofts Application Virtualization.  In the back of my mind, I think doing this will cause problems when trying to debug or run other tasks in Visual Studio but I can't put my finger on any one thing to support my argument.

Has anyone had any experience with Visual Studio 2010 running inside App-V?

I am open to the idea if there are no issues but I am afraid that if this is put in place, we will have issues.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description of App-V [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_App-V) I'd be shocked if the performance was good enough for Visual Studio to be usable.  VS is a very processor and IO intensive application.  Virtualizing its entire operation over the wire is likely drag performance down to unacceptable levels.

I have seen VS perform acceptably on local VMs running VirtualBox, that might be another option for you if platform standardization is your goal.

Comment: Just use Windows 8 Hyper-V feature if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient question, but I found it in a Google search. Just wanted to mention that we've been running Visual Studio 2010 this way for a couple of years, and it's fine. We use it in both a classroom setting and on developer desktops.